# Wordpress paths in VMware virtual machine

Tags: windows, wordpress, localhost, vmware

I am trying to test my local Wordpress site in a VMware virtual machine running Windows, but links are broken! The site is loading, but not the CSS or the images. All the non-wordpress sites are running perfectly.

I assume this has something to do with the paths that Wordpress create, they are still 'localhost' even tho I am accessing my site in windows with the virtual host 'mysite.wp'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use Chrome Ctrl+Shift+I to show the source of the wordpress page, and just find the CSS and image in the source. And to analyse the it.

But I just guess, you may reset the permission of the wordpress folder. If you use Linux as the server, you must give the read permission to the folder. I think.